# Cross ratio: two different views

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

There are I think at least two views on the cross ratio of 4 points even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio gives two definitions

And I was wondering what is the relation between the two

**The Geometrical view:**

The cross ratio of 4 points A,B;X,Y is

$$ CR_g =\frac{d(A,Y) d(B,X)}{d(A,X) d(B,Y)}$$

Where d(I,J) is the distance between I and J.

**The Algebraic view:**

The cross ratio of four (complex) numbers a,b,x,y is:

$$ CR_a=\frac{(y-a) (x-b)}{(x-a)(y-b)}$$

**Wondering / Questions**

Points in a plane can be represented by complex numbers  and this made me  wonder:

What is the relationship between the two cross ratio views  if $A,B,X,Y$ and $a,b,x,y $ represent the same points.

And I also would like to see a proof of that relation.

**Explorations:**

When the points A,B,X,Y are on a line then the cross ratio's are equal

When the points are on a circle $CR_a$ is a real number (see reference in comments)

Comment: Depending on your familiarity with the complex plane and [Mobius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Cross-ratio_preservation), this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932845) probably sums it up most succinctly (+1 for the question and exploration thereof, btw).

Comment: Thanks by the way the proof is only that $CR_a$ is real it doesn't proof that $CR_a\text{4 points on circle} = CR_g {same points} $

Comment: But yes, it does, since $d(X,Y)=|x-y|\,$, so if $CR_a$ is real then $|CR_a| =CR_g\,$.

Comment: I am exploring $d(X,Y)=|x-y| $ at the moment seems to open another can of worms found two different (unequal?) equations for $|x-y|^2$

Comment: @Willemien I don't even see how $CR_g$ is a valid representation of the cross ratio. You can't even get negative values out of it, so there will never be harmonic sets. It would make sense to use a *signed* distance, and then I don't think there is any difference.

Comment: @rschwieb both definitions are in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio and also for $CR_a$ you need a coordinate system while for $CR_g $ you only need a distance  function

Comment: The Wikipedia article says _'cross ratio (...) is a number associated with a list of four **collinear** points'_ and, additionally, _'where an orientation of the line determines the **sign of each distance**'_.

Comment: @Willemien Well, if I'm remembering correctly, you need a Desarguesian projective plane to talk about cross ratios. Then in theory the Desarguesian plane determines a division ring that coordinatizes it (and any lines it contains.) So the two are equivalent (although there is a great deal of work to make the connections plain.) CiaPan's comment is a good followup to what I was trying to say.