# $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4 \in \mathrm C$ lie on a circle. $(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4)$ is their cross ratio. Then $arg(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = 0$ or $\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4 \in \mathrm C$ lie on a generalized circle. $(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4)$ is their cross ratio. Then $arg(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = 0$ or $\pi$. My textbook uses this to show that this cross ratio is real (in fact, if the argument is either $0$ or $\pi$ then it is real). A seperate proof of the fact that the cross ratio of these points is real I found at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932827/812647. I was thinking that the book is using Euler's formula somehow, but now I don't see how it could work. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a generalized circle?

Comment: Is a "generalized circle" the same as either a circle or a line?

Comment: @coffeemath yes

Comment: Sorry, I had to omit the word generalized as the answer will suffice me in either case

Comment: @JeanMarie I have already said that in my question. The book implies that property from the statement in my question, not the contrary.

Comment: In fact the properties are equivalent...

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, but the book is taking a different approach. It states the property in my question, to imply the property you are stating. Your approach first shows the second one to imply the first one.